# How to apply the elementor theme builder custom page to my woocommerce default shop page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, content-management-system, elementor

I'm new to wordpress and I just created a website for online store using wordpress. I want to apply the customized page of woocommerce shop to the default woocommerce shop page, and I'm using Elementor theme builder. I already created the page and customize page as I want. Then I saved and applied the customization to shop page

[image]

The problem is after I applied the theme to the default woocommerce shop page, the shop page still redirect to the same old default woocommerce shop page not the one that I already customized before. I watched some YT tutorials but in the video their customized shop page looked perfectly fine after they applied the theme. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

In your WordPress admin page click **WooCommerce** under Menu. Click **Settings** sub-menu and choose **Products** tab. Under **Products**, in **Shop Page** field choose the shop page you want and save the changes. Now your shop page displayed will be the one you chose in the admin page. You will be no longer redirected to the default one. Please refer to the screenshot below

[image]